# Find top n nodes to a particular node based on weight between them - neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to write a cypher query in neo4j for the following scenario:

Suppose there are n nodes, each node has a relationship with all the other nodes and the relationship has a weight(less than 1 and as type float).
 Ex: there are 6 nodes, p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6 and there is weight for p1-p3,p2-p3,p1-p2 ... (nCr relationships). If I give a parameter as "p2" and ask to fetch the connecting nodes with the score in descending order(like top 3 nodes).

I am unable to think of any solution for now. The actual number of nodes is 45 and I need 4 connecting nodes to a particular node.

Example below:
suppose the following is my CSV for products:

```
1,Chai
2,Chang
3,Aniseed Syrup
4,Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning
5,Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix
```

and a snippet for their relationships(not writing the complete list because it is nCr and it would be too long):

```
1,2,0.0
1,3,0.5364545606371
1,4,0.63314842736745
1,5,0.15688579582258
2,3,0.0
2,4,0.0
2,5,0.0
2,6,0.0
```

I ran the following query to create the nodes and their relation:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///products.csv' AS row
WITH toInteger(row[0]) AS productId, row[1] AS productName
MERGE (p:Product {productId: productId})
  SET p.productName = productName
RETURN count(p)

LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///mapping.csv' AS row
WITH toInteger(row[0]) AS productId1,toInteger(row[1]) as productId2,toFloat(row[2]) as score
MATCH (p1:Product {productId: productId1})
MATCH (p2:Product {productId: productId2})
MERGE (p1)-[rel:SCORE {score:score}]-(p2)
RETURN count(rel)
```

Now if I want to query let's say neighbors of node "2" with weights in decreasing order(LIMIT x - I can define the limit), I am unable to write the query for this.

Comment: do you have an example of something you have tried?

Comment: Hey, thanks, I just edited the query and added the example, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine an `ORDER BY` with a `LIMIT` query to get the higher weights.

I don't know how you data is being mapped, but you can run the query ordering by the relationship weights and limit the query by 3 results. So you will have what you need.

I believe this tutorial can help:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_limit_clause.htm